# How to create a dag in airflow, stored on server

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to connect and create dag in airflow, that hosts on some server. I understand how to do it on local host, but have no ideas how to do it remotely.Is there any tips how to do it?

I found airflow api, but it doesn't have functions to create dags. I'm new to airflow, so any hints will be welcome.

Comment: Upload the dag to the server via whatever mechanism availble

Comment: Or use version control and have airflow read from the repository

Comment: Or put it in a server-accessible storage device or on the cloud like s3 and read from there

Comment: @drum So there is no options to establish connection to airflow somehow and create dags from local host so they will be displayed on server?

Comment: there is none..

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/manage-dags-files.html